# How to check if a string is a discord name in python?

Tags: python, sorting, discord.py

I have a sheet where I'm sorting different columns and I have a column where there are supposed to be only discord names(example: name#0000).
Can I check that with discord.py, if not how should I check it?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using discord names instead of ID's?

Comment: Yes. I'm working with a sheet that contains responses from a google form. People are supposed to enter their discord name so that I can contact them later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `If string in string` syntax in Python.

For example:

```
If "#" in name:
        do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name in the following way.
Let's say you want to check when a player joins your server:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    if find_in_record(member.name):
        do something
    else:
        kick_member() //Depends on you
```

The `member.name` property will return you a str which will be the name (in name#XYZW).

For the `find_in_record` function you can use the [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) module